# VueJS Webpack alias ignored in Gitlab CI / Pipelines

Tags: vue.js, webpack, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am using a Webpack alias in my `<projectRoot>/vue.config.js` defined as:

```
module.exports = {  
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/app/'
    : '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': 'C:\\Path\\To\\Project\\src'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly to allow me to import VueJS components from other components with the following syntax:

```
<script>
import CheckboxInput from '@/components/inputs/CheckboxInput.vue'

...
</script>
```

However in my gitlab pipeline I am getting the following error in the `build:exec` step of the `build` stage:

```
$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ vue-cli-service build
-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors14:39:07
These dependencies were not found:
* @/components/collections/statistics/EmailStatisticsCollection.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Dashboard.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* @/components/collections/statistics/PrintStatisticsCollection.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Dashboard.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/components/collections/statistics/EmailStatisticsCollection.vue @/components/collections/statistics/PrintStatisticsCollection.vue
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

My `gitlab-ci.yml` is defined as:

```
stages:
  - setup
  - build
  - test

variables:
  GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR\<..>\client
  PIPELINE_UTILS_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR\PipelineUtils

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .env.local

before_script:
  - Copy-Item $PIPELINE_UTILS_PATH\client.env $GIT_CLONE_PATH\.env.local

setup:install:
  tags:
    - vuejs
  stage: setup
  script:
    - yarn install
    
build:lint:
  tags:
    - vuejs
  stage: build
  needs: ["setup:install"]
  script:
    - yarn run lint

build:exec:
  tags:
    - vuejs
  stage: build
  needs: ["setup:install"]
  script:
    - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist

test:unit:
  tags:
    - vuejs
  stage: test
  needs: ["build:exec"]
  script:
    - yarn run test:unit
```

The scripts are defined in the package.json to use the vue-cli-service:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

I can't find anything online and I am more of a backend-dev than front-end so I am a little bit out of my depth. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Vue CLI by default aliases @ to <projectRoot>/src, there should be no reason to do it manually.  I'm not sure if this is related to the error but couldn't hurt to try removing the `configureWebpack` block.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the tip, maybe I am using an older version or it is because of plugins in VS-Code but I was forced to do it while I was setting up my project.I tried removing it and am still getting the same error

Comment: Hm, the fact that you were forced to do that in itself may suggest a larger dependency problem.  If possible, it might be worth starting a fresh project with the latest CLI and moving src files over.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't start fresh, but maybe i can upgrade the CLI less destructively, if I figure it out i'll post the answer here, thanks!